# Azure-pipeline build sometimes returns error

Tags: build, azure-devops

Sometimes when building c# app in azure devops I receive the error :

> Error C50518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported.

THis is not deterministic. Sometimes fails and sometimes goes correct. No changes in source code between builds. Any idea what can be a problem?

Comment: The cause might be in build pipeline, You can check the settings for nuget restore task, or use dotnet restore, or set the restoreNugetPackages option of build task to true, to use the newest version of tasks.

Comment: Have you checked the Nuget restore tasks by Levi's suggestions? In case your are building a .net core project, then please also try `dotnet restore` task instead of the nuget restore.

Comment: Yes - i used that. However this issue stops appearing before I did that option anyway. Have no clue why. Anyway thanks for information.